# Google Maps APIv3 - how to overlay multiple markers with different png images

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I'm currently working on a project which involves plotting lots of custom markers onto a map, then creating a popup page when clicked. This problem i'm having, being a newbie at javascript is getting a second marker image showing on the map. So far, i have the following code, as you see, the 'camera' icons work... but needing the 'caltex' to work also...:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-43.54654110763488, 172.6156002235225);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 11,
      center: latlng,
      navigationControl: false,
      scaleable: false,
      draggable:false,


      navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.ANDROID,position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT},
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP


    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);


  setMarkers(map, webcams, caltex);
  }


  /**
 * Data for the markers consisting of a name, a LatLng and a zIndex for
 * the order in which these markers should display on top of each
 * other.
 */
var webcams = [
  ['Anzac Dr ', -43.51129867148775, 172.7162349879427, 9], 
  ['QEII', -43.48499827165804, 172.6179431987025, 8], 
  ['Yaldhurst Russley', -43.52069820902269, 172.5344992587786, 7],
  ['Waimakariri Bridge', -43.47192540674842, 172.5693997383076, 6],
  ['Dyers Linwood', -43.54654110763488, 172.6956002235225, 4],
  ['Main North W', -43.4513336384715, 172.6278547889116, 5],
  ['Main North N', -43.4509480091774, 172.6386309983553, 3],
  ['Memorial Ave', -43.49318192393784, 172.5499633557023, 2],
  ['The Hub', -43.54341394837794, 172.5256827185488, 1]

];


/** Markers for caltex stations **/

var caltex = [
  ['Caltex VIC', -41.01785817829983, 174.91504669189453, 11], //Corner High & Brunswick Streets
  ['Caltex Porirua', -41.01785817829983, 174.91504669189453, 10],  //Parumoana Street
  ['Caltex Railway Avenue', -41.01785817829983, 174.91504669189453, 9], //20 Railway Avenue
  ['Olympic Service Station', -41.23076651060946, 174.8100757598877, 8], //Corner Holland Crescent & Vogel Street
  ['Caltex Rimutaka', -41.2346071181492, 174.80685710906982, 7], //1193 Fergusson Drive North
  ['Caltex Wellington Airport', -41.243384802383986, 174.81380939483643, 6], //Corner Calabar Road & Broadway
  ['Caltex Wainuiomata', -41.29338219297847, 174.78076457977295, 4], //14-16 The Strand
  ['Caltex Upper Hutt', -41.301958541159564, 174.7844123840332, 5], //749-755 Fergusson Drive
  ['Caltex Stokes Valley', -41.286771831897774, 174.77312564849854, 3], //7 Stokes Valley Road, Stokes Valley
  ['Caltex Newtown', -41.285127199004215, 174.7728681564331, 2], //224 Riddiford Street
  ['Caltex Basin Reserve', -41.30211973991373, 174.7792625427246, 1] //28 Adelaide Road

];


function setMarkers(map, locations) {
  // Add markers to the map

  // Marker sizes are expressed as a Size of X,Y
  // where the origin of the image (0,0) is located
  // in the top left of the image.

  // Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker
  // increase in the X direction to the right and in
  // the Y direction down.
  var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('camera.png',
      // This marker is 32 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
      new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
      // The origin for this image is 0,0.
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
      new google.maps.Point(0, 0));


  var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('camera_shadow.png',
      // The shadow image is larger in the horizontal dimension
      // while the position and offset are the same as for the main image.
      new google.maps.Size(37, 32),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      new google.maps.Point(0, 32));
      // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon.
      // The type defines an HTML <area> element 'poly' which
      // traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points. The final
      // coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first
      // coordinate.
  var shape = {
      coord: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1],
      type: 'poly'
  };



  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var cameras = locations[i];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(cameras[1], cameras[2]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        shadow: shadow,
        icon: image,
        shape: shape,
        title: cameras[0],
        zIndex: cameras[3]
    });
  }



    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var caltex = locations[i];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(caltex[1], caltex[2]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        shadow: shadow,
        icon: image,
        shape: shape,
        title: caltex[0],
        zIndex: caltex[3]
    });
  }
}

      var marker = newGMarker(LatLng,cameras)

</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:450px; height:500px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you encapsulated the marker logic into setMarkers() so that you could call it once for each type of marker. However you only call it once. You need to

```
setMarkers(map, webcams);
setMarkers(map, caltex);
```